# Ruby on Rails user queue system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, queue, arduino

I would like to create a Ruby on Rails application that would allow users to control the serial port of the host server. To keep some order to the serial commands, I would like to have some sort of queue system that would only allow one user at a time to issue commands, with a time limit. When their time expires, the next user in the queue is given control.

Has anything similar been created? I am looking for advice as to pre-existing gems or plugins that can be modified to fit this need, or whether I should try and roll my own.

I will be using the [ruby-serial](http://ruby-serialport.rubyforge.org/) library to connect to an Arduino. I would also like to authenticate users via Twitter/Facebook [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Answer (score 0):

[Async Observer](http://async-observer.rubyforge.org/) is by far my favorite for asynchronous job queue execution.

If you built it with [gearman](http://gearman.org/) you could synchronously manipulate such shared resources as well, even on a distributed system.